# undefined reference to dlsym dlerror when installing CGNS on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to install CGNS on ubuntu 20.04. When running `./build-cgns.sh` inside bin ; I get these errors:
undefined reference to dlsym
undefined reference to dlerror
Can anyone help with this? I search on [the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956640/linux-c-error-undefined-reference-to-dlopen/956698#956698) and found out that adding a flag of `-ldl` to the linker option may solve the problem. But,as I am checking inside the file of config-cgns.sh ; there are these lines

```
if [ $TRAVIS_OS_NAME = "linux" ]; then
  export FLIBS="-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl"
  export LIBS="-Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl"
  OPTS="--enable-parallel --enable-cgnstools --with-tcl=/usr/lib --with-tk=/usr/lib"
  autoconf
else
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is really simpler.

You can use [packages from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/libcgns) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcgns-dev cgns-convert
```

and then use it as it was planned. The `cgns-convert` package contains [many executables](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/cgns-convert/filelist).

Comment: Thanks! Does this help me to compile the code which contains "cgnslib.h"?

Comment: Yes, this header file is contained in [`libcgns-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libcgns-dev/filelist) package.